# Django-easy-pdf: xhtml2pdf reporting reportlab 2.2+ is required, but 3.0 installed

Tags: python, django, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to give `django-easy-pdf` a go, but I'm having problems installing dependencies.

I get `ImportError: No module named xhtml2pdf.default` when running Django.

To attempt fixing, I did a `pip install xhtml2pdf`, but that yields `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyPdf (from xhtml2pdf)`.

So let's do a `pip install --allow-unverified pyPdf pyPdf` to get around that. This completed without issues. When repeating the `pip install xhtml2pdf`, the software gets installed without an issue.

However, when launching Django 1.6, I get: `ImportError: Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!`.

I do have reportlab 2.2 or higher installed though, since a `pip freeze` lists 3.0.

It looks like this is hardcoded in a few files (`util.py` and `__init__.py`):

```
if not (reportlab.Version[0] == "2" and reportlab.Version[2] >= "1"):
    raise ImportError("Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!")

if not REPORTLAB22:
    raise ImportError, "Reportlab Toolkit Version 2.2 or higher needed"
```

How can this be fixed (except to remove these checks from the source)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author mentions on https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf:

```
django-easy-pdf depends on:
  django>=1.5.1
  git+https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf.git
```

That specific version needs to be installed, and not the one available in pypi. First uninstall xhtml2pdf and pypdf using `pip uninstall`, then do:

`pip install git+https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf.git`